# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Getting the error stated above.

I tried switching the wheres to havings in the while loop but have had no luck. I don't know if being in the while loop is breaking things or what?

The Goal is to bet a table with items that are available using data stored in the equip_ava temp table and subtracting based on if the item is out based the invoices.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s int(5);
DECLARE m int(5);
DECLARE o date;
DECLARE i date;
DECLARE a int(3);
DECLARE e int(3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS equip_out;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE equip_out
SELECT line_items.invoice_number,date_out,date_due_in,equipment_qty,line_items.equipment_id FROM invoices join line_items
group by Sequence;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS equip_ava;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE equip_ava
SELECT equipment_id,equipment_total FROM equipment
GROUP BY equipment_id;

SET @s = 1;
SET @m = MAX(line_items.Sequence);
    WHILE @s <= @m DO
        SELECT date_out INTO @o FROM invoices join line_items
            WHERE Sequence=@s
            GROUP BY Sequence;

        SELECT date_due_in INTO @i FROM invoices join line_items
            WHERE Sequence=@s
            GROUP BY Sequence;

        IF daily BETWEEN @o AND @i THEN
            SELECT equipment_qty INTO @a FROM line_items
            WHERE Sequence=@s
            GROUP BY Sequence;

            SELECT equipment_id INTO @e FROM line_items
            WHERE Sequence=@s
            GROUP BY Sequence;

            UPDATE equip_ava
            SET equipment_total=equipment_total-@a
            WHERE equipment_id=@e;
        END IF;
        SET @s=@s+1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT * FROM equip_ava;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly use an aggregation function in a stored procedure (or any `SET` statement for that matter); it needs to be part of a `SELECT`. You need to change that line to

```
SET @m = (SELECT MAX(Sequence) FROM line_items);
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(Sequence) INTO @m FROM line_items;
```

Note that you have declared a lot of variables but are not actually using them. `@s` is a global variable, `s` is the local variable in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue need to change

```
SET @m = MAX(line_items.Sequence);
```

to

```
SELECT @m = MAX(line_items.Sequence) FROM line_items;
```

Comment: That code will not work as you expect; it will always return either 0 or 1 as `@m = MAX(line_items.Sequence)` is a boolean expression. It needs to be `@m := MAX(line_items.Sequence)` (note the `:`). Also note my comment about variables in my answer.